# Intercepting json in https(not http) with a python cgi script

Tags: java, python, cgi

I  am  sending  json  string  in  an  https  post request  to  an  apache  servert(request  sends  json  data  to  a  cgi-bin  script  that  actually  is   a  python  script).  Am  using  a  standard  cgi  call  -

```
 f=open("./testfile",  "w+")                                             
 f.write("usageData  json  =  \n")   
 <b>form = cgi.FieldStorage()  
 formList = ['Data']      
 str = form['Data'].value
 str = json.dumps(backupstr)
 </b>      
 print  backupstr
```

to  read  the  json  string  in  the  url.  Problem  is  that  the  script  is  not  reading  the  json  in  the  url  even  though  the  script  is  getting  fired (the  basic  print  statements  are  executing ...).  This  is  how  am   sending  data  from  the  post  side :

```
  HttpsURLConnection  connection  =   null;
  try{
     connection  = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                 "application/json");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
                  Integer.toString(jsonstring.getBytes().length));
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
     connection.setUseCaches (false);
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setDoOutput(true);

     //Send request
     DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                     connection.getOutputStream ());
     //wr.writeBytes(jsonstring);
     wr.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode(jsonstring,  "UTF-8"));
     wr.flush ();
     wr.close ();

     //Get Response 
     InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
     BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     String line;
     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
     while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         response.append(line);
     }
     rd.close();
     //response = httpClient.execute(request); 
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
      System.out.println("Exception  "  +  e.getMessage());
      throw  e;
   }
```

I  suspect  am  missing  one  or  more  of  the  connection.setRequestProperty()  settings  on  the  sending  end  that's   why  it's  firing  the  script  but  not  reading  the  json  string  in  the  url ...what   am  I  doing  wrong ...?

Comment: Isn't that second block of code Java? (If so, it would be a good idea to add that tag to your question)

Comment: How long is the json string?  There are limitations of the length of a `GET` variable value on both server and client.

Comment: Yes it's  not  a  GET  request,  it's  a  POST  request  with  json  string  in  the  url ..

Comment: Does this work over HTTP? It seems to me that you are passing json directly from the client, but trying to accesss it as form data on the server.